# Microsoft Graph findMeetingTimes throws ErrorInternalServerError

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When looking for an available meeting time the server returns a `500` without further explanation.

Request: POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/findMeetingTimes

```
{
    "locationConstraint": {
        "isRequired": "true",
        "suggestLocation": "false",
        "locations": [
            {
                "resolveAvailability": "true",
                "locationEmailAddress": "..."
            }
        ]
    },
    "timeConstraint": {
        "activityDomain":"unrestricted",
        "timeslots": [
            {
                "start": {
                    "dateTime": "2018-08-24T16:00:00",
                    "timeZone": "UTC"
                },
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": "2018-08-24T23:59:59",
                    "timeZone": "UTC"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
        "message": "An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "9e628ded-5750-497e-b54e-efe9b7184403",
            "date": "2018-08-24T16:35:30"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `findMeetingTimes` can't handle meetings which have a start or end `dateTime` with milliseconds. Also seconds need to be truncated to 00.

Works

```
"dateTime": "2018-08-24T16:00:00",
```

Breaks `findMeetingTimes`

```
"dateTime": "2018-08-24T16:00:00.791",
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your descriptions, I suppose you want to look for an available meeting time.

Base on my test, If we set the value of the “start to end” time is less than the value of 'meetingDuration' Field. I got same error as you described.

If no meeting duration is specified, findMeetingTimes uses the default of 30 minutes.

From test above, we should set value of “start to end” time greater than the value of the 'meetingDuration' Field. Or greater than 30 if 'meetingDuration' was no set (because by default it will be 30 minutes